# I cannot find the post method when doing a httpcallout through flows

Tags: httpcalloutmock, httppost

I am trying to convert an opportunity to sales agreement through HTTPCallOut Action using flows and it does not give me an option to select the POST method, it only has the GET method.

I created a legacy Named credential with the URL - https://xxx-c1.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/connect/manufacturing/sales-agreements.

Any inputs in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [ability to POST](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5) is, at the time of this answer, in beta. You must opt in in order to use it. Please read the help topic link provided for more information.